# Como somar valores provenientes de uma estrutura for?

Tags: python, for, elementos, soma

Então, estou precisando resolver um probleminha no meu código (sou bem newb), estou apenas programando porque preciso disso para o meu TCC, não sei muita coisa de python mas estou tentando me virar.

Na linha 126 tem aquela formula `del_Frs_uth`....e ela me retorna vários valores, pois tenho vários valores de `Alpha_e` que são calculados segundo uma fórmula que recebe valores de uma "estrutura for", onde esta estrutura for em questão(linha 102) depende de mais algumas "estruturas for" mais acima...Como eu faria para somar todos os valores de `del_Frs_uth`???

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EDIT: resolvi criar um exemplo para simplificar a pergunta, segue abaixo

```
K = 5
N = 2
L = 5
del_a = 1.5
del_b = 0.5
del_c = 0.01

for i in range(1, K + 1, 1):
    a = i*del_a

    for k in range(1, N + 1, 1):
        b = a + (k-1)*del_b

        for j in range(1, L + 1, 1):
            c = j*del_c
            d = b - c
            print(d)

        #COMO SOMAR OS VALORES DE "d"???
```

existe alguma função que some valores de um vetor? como eu armazenaria os valores de "d" em um vetor?? Obrigado a todos

Comment: Não coloque imagens de código, ao invés disso adicione o código como texto formatando através de `Ctrl + k` ou no botão `{}` do editor da pergunta. Para além disse tente criar um [exemplo minimo verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do problema que tem, para que seja mais facil de obter uma resposta.

Comment: Bom dia Isac, tentei criar um exemplo mais simples! obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi se você quer a soma de todos os `d` ou se você quer um array com todos os `d`, o `res_soma` vai conter a soma e `res_array` vai conter todos elementos

```
K = 5
N = 2
L = 5
del_a = 1.5
del_b = 0.5
del_c = 0.01
res_soma = 0
res_array = []

for i in range(1, K + 1, 1):
    a = i*del_a

    for k in range(1, N + 1, 1):
        b = a + (k-1)*del_b

        for j in range(1, L + 1, 1):
            c = j*del_c
            d = b - c
            res_soma += d
            res_array.insert(len(res_array), d)

print(res_array) #[1.49, 1.48, 1.47, 1.46, 1.45, ...
print(res_soma) #235.99999999999997
```

Comment: pow, era exatamente isso que eu precisava! muito obrigadoo. Qual seria a interpretação desse += d? Para cada iteração vai somando d?

Comment: Exatamente, `res_soma += d` é o mesmo que `res_soma = res_soma + d`

Comment: valeu mano, muito obrigado pela ajuda! abraço.